# не понимаю почему не работает перебор

Tags: python

```py
for x in range (100,1000):
    s = x
    l = 0
    m = 0 
    while x > 0:
        m = m + 1
        if (x % 2) != 0:
            l = l + x % 8
        x = x // 8
    if (m == 14 and l == 3):
        print(m,l,x)
```

[image: вот дана программа]
Ниже на пяти языках программирования записан алгоритм. Получив на вход натуральное десятичное число x, этот алгоритм печатает два числа: L и M. Укажите наибольшее число x, при вводе которого алгоритм печатает сначала 14, а потом 3.

Comment: Оригинал с ЕГЭ можете показать? А ещё можете свой код текстом оформить?

Comment: for x in range (100,1000):
    s = x
    l = 0
    m = 0
    while x > 0:
        m = m + 1
        if (x % 2) != 0:
            l = l + x % 8
        x = x // 8
    if (m == 14 and l == 3):
        print(m,l,x)

Comment: извините что так неудобно

Comment: https://inf-ege.sdamgia.ru/problem?id=15860 вот оригинал с ЕГЭ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В оригинале задания ЕГЭ написан вот такой код:

```py
x = int(input())
 L = 0 
 M = 0
while x > 0 :
    M = M+1
     if (x % 2) != 0:
         L = L + x % 8
     x = x // 8 
print(L) 
print(M)
```

Он подразумевает, что первым числом будет `L`, а вторым — `M`. У Вас же первое число `M`, а второе — `L`, поэтому программа и не выводит значения.

Просто поменяйте местами данными переменные в условии проверки, и всё должно заработать

Comment: поменял местами, теперь в ответе выдает 11 нулей столбиком

Comment: Это оттого, что Вы ещё изменяете оригинальную переменную `x`, хотя она предназначена только для прохода по циклу. Сейчас исправлю

Comment: а, я понял в чем проблема, изменил в принте x на s

Comment: спасибо большое))

Comment: Пожалуйста. Не забудьте отметить данный ответ как верный, нажав на галочку слева от текста :)

Comment: обязательно отмечу)